# Bone Heat Weighting Failed

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am trying to figure out an issue for my student who is having a problem with parenting and skinning his creature. He sent me what he had and I went back and redid it by adding the bones again. When I try to parent it, the message, "bone heat weighting failed" comes up. I have tried removing the double vertices, recalucating the outside, turning on and off the x axis, rotating, scaling, turning on subsurf and I cannot figure out why it isn't working.

I also tried to skin his creature that he originally sent to me following the directions the course gives, but nothing happens and I am not sure if it is because it isn't parented correctly? When I try it doesn't select part of the body like it should.

Any help would be great!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZPqxADetWE

Comment: I looked at this post, but can't figure out how to connect the mesh. I tried removing the double vertices and it still doesn't work.

Comment: please upload you blend file for checking : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34455